# building a feature set for scikit learn

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, prediction

Im using `RandomForestClassifier` for a probability prediction task. I have a featureset of around 50 features and two possible labels - `first team wins` and `second team wins`.

The feature set contains features for both teams, and the way I built it, since I know which team won, was have 50% of the set labeled 1st team wins, and 50% labeled 2nd team wins - with the respective features placed in the correct place in the feature set - for each match in training data, which initially has the winning team as the first one, I swap the features per team and change the label to `second team wins`, using a counter modulo 2.

The problem i see is that if I change the counter to start from 1 or 0, it makes a huge change in the final predictions, meaning that the data-set is asymmetrical. To tackle this problem I tried to add every match twice in normal order where the label is `first team wins` , and reversed with the label being `second team wins`. The question is - how does this affect the behavior of the model? I see some negative effect after making this change, although not enough to be statistically significant. It does however increase the running time for building the feature set and fitting the model obviously.

Will randomizing the label and team order be a more solid approach? what are my options?

Comment: Would you share some of your code with us?

Comment: @Bach - providing a minimal code sample for reproduction would be difficult..

Answer (score 2):

Since you're comparing corresponding team features to each other, an alternative would be to reduce:

```
TeamA: featureA1, featureA2, featureA3 ... featureAN
TeamB: featureB1, featureB2, featureB3 ... featureBN
Output: which team wins
```

to:

```
Input: featureA1-featureB1, featureA2-featureB2, featureA3-featureB3, ..., featureAN - featureBN
Output: positive if team A wins, negative if team B wins
```

and train your classifier on that. The benefit of this approach is that you now have half the number of features to compare, and no longer have to worry about the order of the teams.

Comment: ok, this is an approach worth exploring. but the margin between features is not the same information as the absolute values.

Comment: That's right. Another thing I forgot to add is that the suitability of this approach depends on what your features are, and if it makes sense comparing them that way.

Comment: FYI, this is called the pairwise reduction in learning to rank. It's quite sensible and common.